# Jenkins is not building jobs automatically on push notifications

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Auto job deployment is not triggering in jenkins when performed git push. I have jenkins2.0 and github and jenkins are connected (Test connection is jenkins gives me tick mark (Successful integration) and when I click `Build now` button in jenkins, it's fetching latest commits from github and building jobs.

But, auto build deployment is not happening. Could you please help me what is the problem. [image]